# Tempo de execução em desafio de olimpíada de programação

Tags: c

Olá, preciso fazer a seguinte questão: https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p2/2017/f3/arranhaceu/

Eis o enunciado:

> Um arranha-céu residencial possui N andares, numerados de 1 a N. O síndico do arranha-céu está tendo muito trabalho com uma nova regra do corpo de bombeiros. Ele não sabe o porquê, mas os bombeiros apontam um andar k e exigem que o síndico informe o total de pessoas que moram no arranha-céu do andar 1 até o andar k, inclusive. Talvez seja alguma medida de segurança dos bombeiros! O problema é que o prédio tem muitos andares e toda hora tem gente se mudando, passando a morar no arranha-céu, ou indo embora. O síndico precisa cuidar de dois eventos:
>
> - Mudança: alterar o número de pessoas que moram num determinado andar;
> - Bombeiro: informar o total de pessoas que moram do andar 1 até um determinado andar, inclusive.
>
> Dados o número de pessoas que moram em cada andar do arranha-céu inicialmente, e uma sequência de eventos (do tipo Mudança ou Bombeiro), seu programa deve imprimir, para cada evento do tipo Bombeiro, o total de pessoas exigido, no momento do evento!
>
> **Entrada**
>   A primeira linha da entrada contém dois inteiros N e Q, representando, respectivamente, o número de andares e o número de eventos. A segunda linha contém N inteiros Ai, 1 ≤ i ≤ N, indicando o número de pessoas que moram no i-ésimo andar inicialmente. Cada uma das Q linhas seguintes representa um evento e tem uma de duas formas:
>
> - "0 K P", Mudança, alterar o número de pessoas que moram no K-ésimo andar para P pessoas;
> - "1 K", Bombeiro, informar o total de pessoas que moram do andar 1 até o andar K, inclusive.
>
> **Saída**
>   Para cada evento do tipo Bombeiro, seu programa deve imprimir uma linha contendo um inteiro representando o total de pessoas correspondente aquele evento.
>
> **Restrições**
>   1 ≤ N ≤ 105 e 1 ≤ Q ≤ N
>   Há pelo menos um evento do tipo Bombeiro.
>   1 ≤ K ≤ N
>   0 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000 e 0 ≤ P ≤ 1000
>
> **Informações sobre a pontuação**
>
> - Em um conjunto de casos de teste somando 20 pontos, N ≤ 20000
>
> **Exemplos**
>
> Entrada:
>
> ```
> 8 4
> 30 2 0 42 10 11 11 9
> 1 5
> 0 4 12
> 1 5
> 1 1
> ```
>
> Saída:
>
> ```
> 84
> 54
> 30
> ```
>
> Entrada:
>
> ```
> 1 1
> 0
> 1 1
> ```
>
> Saída:
>
> ```
> 0
> ```

O código que fiz é esse:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n, q, k, p, contEventos, evento, totalPessoas, i, pessoas[100000];

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &pessoas[i]);
    }

    for(contEventos = 0; contEventos < q; contEventos++){

        scanf("%d", &evento);
        scanf("%d", &k);

        if(evento == 0){

            scanf("%d", &p);
            pessoas[k - 1] = p;

        }else if(evento == 1){

            totalPessoas = 0;

            for(i = 0; i < k; i++){
                totalPessoas += pessoas[i];
            }

            printf("%d\n", totalPessoas);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pelos casos de teste que eles disponibilizam funciona bem. Porém na hora de submeter a solução, nos outros testes meu código excede o tempo máximo de execução de 1000ms. O que posso fazer pra diminuir este tempo de execução?

Correção do meu código:

> Compilação correta
>
> Fase de testes -- Tempo Limite para cada execução: 1000 ms
>   Teste  1: `........`     (20 pontos)
>   Teste  2: `TTTT`     (0 pontos)
>   Teste  3: `TT`     (0 pontos)
>   Teste  4: `TT`     (0 pontos)
>   Teste  5: `TTTT`     (0 pontos)
>
> Total: 20 pontos (de 100 possíveis)
>
> Legenda:
>   `.`: resultado correto
>   `X`: resultado incorreto
>   `E`: erro em tempo de execução
>   `M`: Referência a memória inválida
>   `S`: programa não gerou saída
>   `T`: tempo limite excedido
>   `V`: violação de recursos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## O seu problema

O problema é o seguinte: Imagine um prédio com 100.000 andares e que os bombeiros pedem insistentemente milhares de vezes para saber quantas pessoas têm até o último andar. Isso vai fazer o seu programa consumir um tempão calculando e recalculando o `totalPessoas`. Cada consulta percorreria **n** andares e são **q** consultas no total, logo o tempo nesse caso vai ser proporcional a **O(nq)**.

## Outras soluções que não funcionam

Você poderia pensar em uma abordagem de recalcular tudo só quando alguém se mudar e guardar o resultado numa variável. Mas daí, deve haver algum teste onde ocorrem milhares de mudanças e o seu programa vai de novo estourar o tempo com **O(nq)**.

Você pode pensar em fazer um array auxiliar que mostre o acumulado de pessoas até cada um dos andares, para consultá-lo quando os bombeiros chegarem. Mas nesse caso, você teria que reconstruir a tabela quando houverem mudanças a partir do andar onde ocorreu a mudança, e deve haver algum teste onde ocorrem milhares de mudanças no primeiro andar, e o resultado é novamente **O(nq)**.

## Divisão e conquista

Talvez uma abordagem de dividir e conquistar seja a solução. Se você manter uma contagem do número de pessoas na metade inferior do prédio em uma variável (vamos chamar de `x`), a consulta dos bombeiros na metade superior ficará bem mais rápida, pois você não precisará recontar a metade inferior, basta usar o valor `x`). Da mesma forma, se houver alguma mudança na metade inferior do prédio, você só precisará recalcular o valor `x` da metade inferior do prédio, sem se preocupar com os valores da metade superior.

Usando-se essa ideia recursivamente, subdivide-se cada bloco de andares pela metade até chegar a um ponto onde se tem um bloco de apenas um andar. Então junta-se os blocos de 2-em-2 somando-se o número de pessoas em cada andar. Depois, junta-se esses blocos maiores de 2-em-2 também formando blocos ainda maiores até você ter um bloco que representa o prédio inteiro.

Para um prédio de 12 andares, o resultado é o que está abaixo:

[image: Prédio de 12 andares]

Andares que não existem por estarem depois do último são considerados como zeros. Por exemplo, o 193 da quarta coluna deveria agrupar 8 andares ao invés de 4, mas o prédio acaba antes disso e portanto o que tem depois são apenas zeros.

## Como descobrir quantas pessoas têm até algum andar?

Ok, mas como podemos saber quantas pessoas têm nos 9 primeiros andares, por exemplo?

A resposta é que os 8 primeiros andares têm 134 pessoas e o 9º tem 77. Logo a resposta é 134 + 77 = 211 pessoas.

E se quisermos os 7 primeiros andares?

A resposta é que os 4 primeiros tem 88, o 5º e o 6º juntos têm 9 e o 7º tem 24. Logo a resposta é 88 + 9 + 24 = 121 pessoas.

E se em um prédio maior que esse, quisermos até o 42º andar?

Nesse caso pega-se o número de pessoas dos 32 primeiros andares, mais o número de pessoas dos 8 andares do 31º ao 40º e então o número de pessoas do 41º junto com o 42º.

Mas como saber quais desses blocos de tamanhos diferentes escolher?

É só olhar para o número escrito em binário. Por exemplo:

- 9 é 1001, ou seja, 8 + 1. Então pega-se um bloco correspondente a 8 andares seguido de um bloco de 1 andar.
- 7 é 111, ou seja, 4 + 2 + 1. Então pega-se um bloco correspondente a 4 andares seguido de mais um de 2 andares e então um de 1 andar.
- 42 é 101010, ou seja, 32 + 8 + 2. Então pega-se um bloco de 32 andares, um de 8 e um de 2.

Na imagem do prédio, o próprio prédio azul corresponde aos blocos de tamanho 1, a fila amarela à sua direita os de tamanho 2, depois os de tamanho 4, 8, 16 e assim por diante. Dessa forma, é possível saber de quais colunas os blocos devem ser escolhidos.

Note que nunca dois blocos da mesma coluna são acessados nesta operação.

## Como mudar a quantidade de moradores de um andar?

Essa é fácil, altera-se o bloco correspondente ao andar e todos os blocos à direita dele. Os demais blocos não precisam ser recalculados.

## Complexidade da solução.

Quantas blocos (cada um numa coluna diferente) cada operação de mudança ou de contagem pelos bombeiros é acessado?

- Num prédio de 1 andar, 1 bloco.
- Num prédio de 2 andares, 2 blocos.
- Num prédio de 3 a 4 andares, 3 blocos.
- Num prédio de 5 a 8 andares, 4 blocos.
- Num prédio de 9 a 16 andares, 5 blocos.
- Num prédio de 17 a 32 andares, 6 blocos.
- ...
- Num prédio de 32.769 a 65.536 andares, 17 blocos.
- Num prédio de 65.537 a 131.072 andares, 18 blocos.

Isso começou a ficar legal. Nesse caso, qualquer operação que exija a recontagem das pessoas (seja a mudança ou seja os bombeiros) vai acabar consumindo tempo proporcional a **1 + log<sub>2</sub> n**. Portanto a complexidade total é **O(q log<sub>2</sub> n)**. Considerando que **n** é 100.000, e que **1 + log<sub>2</sub> n** é próximo a 18, isso claramente é bem melhor que qualquer solução **O(nq)**.

## Organizando a solução

Agora precisamos ver como organizamos isso na memória. Podemos usar uma matriz com 18 x 100.000, afinal de contas, 18 é o máximo de colunas de blocos que temos e 100.000 é o máximo de andares. Declaramos então `pessoas[CAMADAS][MAX_N]`, onde `CAMADAS` é 18 e `MAX_N` é 100.000.

Os blocos são organizados sequencialmente em cada fileira da matriz assim:

[image: matriz]

Com essa lógica, o bloco `i` da coluna `t` é pai dos blocos `2 * i` e `2 * i + 1` da coluna `t - 1`. Isso é importante para construir esses blocos depois que o prédio for montado:

```
pessoas[t][i] = pessoas[t - 1][2 * i] + pessoas[t - 1][2 * i + 1];
```

Pelo lado contrário, o bloco `k` da coluna `t` é filho do bloco `k / 2` da coluna `t + 1` (e portanto `k / 2` é pai de `k`). Note que essa divisão é inteira.

Assim sendo, o irmão do bloco `i` em uma coluna `t` qualquer é o bloco `i ^ 1` nessa mesma coluna. Esse `^ 1` serve para inverter o último bit de um número, transformando um número par num ímpar e um ímpar num par.

Ao atualizar o valor do andar `k` (na verdade `k - 1`, pois como você já percebeu, esse `- 1` serve para começar a contar do 0), o bloco pai vai receber a soma dos valores dos filhos. Logo, a expressão para atualizar um bloco pai na coluna `t` a partir do valor alterado no filho `k` é:

```
pessoas[t][k / 2] = pessoas[t - 1][k] + pessoas[t - 1][k ^ 1];
```

Para os bombeiros verificarem o número de pessoas até determinado andar `k`, para cada camada `t`, olha-se os blocos `k` dessa camada. Para atualizar o `k` na hora de pular da camada `t` para a camada `t + 1`, basta fazer `k /= 2;`. No entanto, só são considerados os blocos que correspondem aos bits 1 tal como já explanado, o que pode ser verificado com `k & 1`, considerando-se que o `k` está mudando nessa iteração. Ou seja:

```
for (t = 0; t < CAMADAS && k > 0; t++) {
    if (k & 1) totalPessoas += pessoas[t][k - 1];
    k /= 2;
}
```

## Código resultante

No final, o resultado é isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_N 100000
#define CAMADAS 18

int main() {

    int n, q, k, p, t, contEventos, evento, totalPessoas, i, pessoas[CAMADAS][MAX_N];

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &pessoas[0][i]);
    }
    for (; i < MAX_N; i++) {
        pessoas[0][i] = 0;
    }
    for (t = 1; t < CAMADAS; t++) {
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_N / 2; i++) {
            pessoas[t][i] = pessoas[t - 1][2 * i] + pessoas[t - 1][2 * i + 1];
        }
        for (; i < MAX_N; i++) {
            pessoas[t][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (contEventos = 0; contEventos < q; contEventos++) {
        scanf("%d", &evento);
        scanf("%d", &k);

        if (evento == 0) {
            scanf("%d", &p);
            k--;
            pessoas[0][k] = p;
            for (t = 1; t < CAMADAS; t++) {
                pessoas[t][k / 2] = pessoas[t - 1][k] + pessoas[t - 1][k ^ 1];
                k /= 2;
            }
        } else if (evento == 1) {
            totalPessoas = 0;

            for (t = 0; t < CAMADAS && k > 0; t++) {
                if (k & 1) totalPessoas += pessoas[t][k - 1];
                k /= 2;
            }

            printf("%d\n", totalPessoas);
        }

        // Para mostrar a tabela.
        /*for (int y = 0; y < CAMADAS; y++) {
            printf("\n|");
            for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
                printf("%d ", pessoas[y][z]);
            }
            printf("|\n");
        }*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Os laços que têm `pessoas[0][i] = 0;` e `pessoas[t][i] = 0;` servem para limpar as posições não utilizadas da tabela para evitar que sujeira/lixo pré-existente na memória atrapalhem o cálculo.

Note que a tabela desperdiça uma boa quantidade de memória, pois grande parte das posições dela ficam sempre vazias mesmo para um prédio de 100.000 andares cheio de gente em todos os andares. A tabela tem 1.800.000 posições, e até é possível reduzir-se o tamanho dela com algumas operações matemáticas para 199.985 posições, que é o tamanho mínimo dela. No entanto o código para fazer isso ficaria bem mais complexo e mais difícil de entender e o ganho de desempenho seria desprezível.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/kOnHgh)

Comment: Achei excelente essa sua abordagem ao problema, que ainda não me tinha ocorrido. E suspeito que era a solução que o autor do problema esperava.

Comment: Sua resposta foi muito melhor do que eu esperava, parabéns. Porém eu achei um tanto confusa a resolução. Vc usou operadores de bit que eu nem sabia sobre. Analisando com um pouco mais de tempo tenho certeza que vou conseguir entender, mas o ponto é, visto que essa questão foi dada pra alunos do ensino médio, será que não tem uma solução "menos" complexa?

Comment: @AntonyLeme Para alunos do ensino médio é de se esperar soluções mais simplistas como a que você tinha, sem ter limitação de tempo. Agora, exigir o comportamento ótimo disso a partir de alunos do ensino médio é loucura, insanidade, maluquice, crueldade. Há coisas aqui que dependem de conhecimento que só é adquirido lá pelo 5º ou 6º semestre de um curso superior de ciência da computação, e que boa parte dos alunos estuda só pra passar na prova e depois esquece.

Comment: @VictorStafusa entendi. Como se trata de uma olimpíada, imagino que seja da intenção deles cobrar essas coisas a mais. Sua resolução me atentou pra algumas coisas que vou tentar entender melhor, pra talvez ganhar uns pontos a mais em alguma questão. Talvez não seja tão preocupante, já que teoricamente meus concorrentes têm o mesmo nível de conhecimento que eu. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, problemas da OBI tem complexidade o suficiente para serem intercambiados facilmente com os da maratona ACM-ICPC. Então, sim, quem faz essas questões de OBI está pensando em gente que tenha pelo menos uns 4 anos de programação e treino para programação competitiva. Ou seja: pessoas que treinam desde o 6 ano do ensino fundamental